# Contrast feature of ImageMagick convert

Tags: imagemagick

I just want to use the convert command in a way, so that the pictures get in colorspace gray, negated and with a higher contrast.
The colorspace and negation are not a problem, but the contrast is one. I use the following bash script:

```
for i in *
do
    echo $i
    convert $i -colorspace gray gray/$i
    convert gray/$1 -contrast -contrast contrasted/$1
    convert contrasted/$i -negate negated/$i

done
```

I moved the contrast command in every possible position, but there always comes the following error:

```
convert-im6.q16: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `contrasted/' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
convert-im6.q16: unable to open image `contrasted/s5_rechts_abgeschnitten.png': Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2701.
convert-im6.q16: no images defined `negated/s5_rechts_abgeschnitten.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3258.
```

I don't really know what to do, so would be cool if someone got a solution.

Comment: Do you mean `gray/$i`, not `gray/$1`? Same with `contrasted/$1`

Comment: Another way to add contrast is to use -brightness-contrast with  0 for the brightness and some positive value for the contrast, rather than repeated use of -contrast. See https://imagemagick.org/www/script/command-line-options.php#brightness-contrast

Comment: What @emcconville says makes sense. If you used `$1` instead of `$i`, and `$1` is empty, then imagemagick will get told to write to `contrasted/`, and (a) it doesn't know the empty image file extension (explains the first error message); (b) it doesn't write to the file `contrasted/` (explains error 2); (c) the last command can't open `contrasted/s5_rechts_abgeschnitten` because it was never created (explains error 3), and (d) the last command won't write to the file `negated/s5_rechts_abgeschnitten.png` (explains message 4).

Comment: Thanks, that solved my problem. Don't know why I didn't saw that.